Cluster expansion (SFT) vs Loop series Expansion (QFT)
I'm not that involved in Statistical Field Theory (SFT), however i recalled from a course I followed the existence of cluster expansion and it actually exists.
From what I see it's an expansion of the potential in n-interacting particle potentials.
It requires $Z$ to be written as an integral over continuum valued phase space.
Wikipedia says (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_expansion#cite_note-1) that it's different from the usual perturbation theory like loop series expansion, as it will not diverge: I can't understand well this sentence. I'm used to diverging power series when critical points are approached and quantum fluctuations as important as the mean classical value. If this expansion is not diverging, isn't it a miracle? What does this actually mean?
But the real core of my question involves the need of having Z defined over a continuum from $-\infty$ to $\infty$: If that's the case we can deploy Gaussian integrals. From them we can develop the formalism of loop series expansion, expanding the interaction term exponential with Feynmann diagrams.
If instead we have an Ising model, where the possible spin values are $S_{i} \in \{-1,+1\}$, we cannot use Gaussian integrals. Thus we cannot use loop series expansion.
What is usually taught as approximation (yes, montecarlo an RG approaches are non-perturbative, but I want to focus on perturbative approximation or what cluster expansion is defined as) is the poor mean field theory, which represents the tree level of loop series expansions.
Now, mean field is just a way to say: I'm treating my potential as a 1 particle potential.
Cluster expansion leads, for what I understood, to $n$-particle potential terms, where a so called $B_{n}$ is a complicated $n$-particle interaction coupling.
This perturbative approach, however, doesn't use gaussian integrals and, as such, seems to me to be more general than loop series expansion: It can be applied to models like Ising, where the integral over the lattice configuration is discrete and does not range from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.
It even uses diagrammatic representations and studies connected diagrams, so I can't not notice a possible connection (maybe more general on the requirements, as explained above) with loop series expansion.
To sum up:
What are the quirks of Cluster expansion and how is it related to loop series expansion and mean field theory?
